# Shortcut Credentialing to open an app and explorer window

Tags: powershell, credentials, powershell-4.0

I'm attempting to launch a powershell script that requests my password for an admin account for credentials.  Once it has my credentials it opens a powershell shell, launches a windows explorer window, and an application, all with the admin credentials.  Ideally I would also like for the explorer window and shell to open to a specific location but i haven't tried coding that until I get the credentials working correctly.

Currently every time I try the following code I am told that the username and password is incorrect when I know for a fact that it is the correct username and password.

```
$MyCredentials = Get-Credential -Credential ''
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $MyCredentials -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -verb runas"
Start-Process explorer.exe -Credential $MyCredentials
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe' -Credential $MyCredentials
```

Comment: Syntax looks just fine. What's the error exactly like?

Comment: IS this a domain account

Comment: Yes, this is a domain account.  The actual error:

`start-process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or password is incorrect.
At line:3 char:1
+ start-process powershell.exe -Credential $MyCredentials -NoNewWindow  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`